# AWS Change DNS without affecting Workmail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Wix website and in order to connect my AWS domain to it so

1. I changed the Nameservers (in registered domains to Wix)
2. Updated the NS records (in hosted zones to Wix)
   *I noticed (when in hosted zones) that when I click "Hosted Zone Details" it has AWS Name servers.

I have WorkMail set up but now it won't find the correct settings (after it was previously working well) and it has the message: "Your Route 53 hosted zone  for this domain needs to be set as authoritative. To learn how to set a hosted zone as authoritative, see Migrating DNS  in the AWS Route 53 Developer Guide."

So, I'm not sure what to do in order to make my domain work with Wix and have my Workmail working correctly. It seems like one or the other unless I'm missing something, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your right, you need to pick one. I dont believe there is a requirement for either of them where your namesevers are hosted - its just they point you towards their own services as its generally easier to setup ;-)

Your old zone in Route 53 will have MX, TXT and CNAME records specifically for workmail. When you switched nameservers you lost those records. Take a look at this page for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/add-verify-domain-workmail/

Option 1
Leave your nameservers pointing to WIX and re-setup WorkMail

Option 2
Revert your name servers to Route53 and setup WIX to use route53 (im not familar with Wix but this looks about right - https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-domain-to-wix-using-the-pointing-method - basically you create an `A` record for `example.com` and a `CNAME` for `www.example.com` in Route53 with values from Wix.